# How can reduce swimming pool pump vibration through the ground?

Tags: doors, pump, noise

Constant humming noise in my house from my neighbor's swimming pool pump and setup. Its not very loud when standing next to it, but it does generate a humming sound in half of my house (which is about 15 feet from the pump equipment). The pool is about 6 years old. Standing next to the pump I could feel some vibration on the ground.

I was wondering if there is some company in Palm beach county  Florida specialize in putting some sort of barrier to quiet down the noise. Since there is an HOA the structure has to be presentable.
Thanks

[image: Picture of pump setup]

Picture of pump setup and I don't know what all the parts represent-pumps, filters, heater etc.

Comment: Is the pump bolted down or just sitting on the concrete?

Comment: It is bolted down and it is sitting on concrete and not vibrating.

Comment: My pump is not bolted down. It's held in place by the piping. That could make a difference in vibration transfer. Originally you said you could feel vibration.

Comment: Yes when I stood on the soil next to the pump setup I could feel some vibration theough my feet  where I stood. Its is not very strong  but I could feel  it. It is so confusing that I really don't know where the sound is coming from.The houses here are built using cinder blocks and the roof is tile roof.

Comment: Are you sure the pump is the cause? If the neighbor kills the power to the pump, the noise stops as well?

Comment: I don't know if it is the pump or  the pipes .but I do know  when  the pump stops the humming sound goes away and that's for sure. It has quite a few parts to the whole setup. There is the pump,pipes,the filter and I don't know what is  inside the black cage.

Comment: @joe I updated my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 6):

If you can feel the vibration standing next to it that is what's transferring noise into your house. I don't think a barrier will be of much use. My pool pump doesn't make any noticeable vibration.  Doing something to address the vibration would be the route I would go. I added a picture of mine. It isn't bolted down. If I put my hand on the pump I can feel the vibration but I don't feel any on the cement next to it. If you search on Amazon there is such a thing as a pool pump vibration isolation pad. They seem to have good reviews.
[image]

Comment: I will talk to my neighbor about putting a vibration isolation pad.That would  be quite reasonable .Appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a barrier, you need *isolation*.

Talk to your neighbor about the problem, and request that they lift the pump onto some sort of elastic suspension platform and install soft connectors to the plumbing. This will dramatically reduce energy transmission to the ground.

Comment: Can you expalin a little more on "install soft connectors to the plumbing"I want to find out whether I need to talk to a pool company or a contractor and I will pay for it.My neighbor doesn't seem to have a noise problem even though its it right next to their house.We are friends.

Comment: Not really. Find something that's not hard plastic. I'm not a pool plumber. :)